# How to send push notification to specific user in Expo Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications

I'm working with Expo react native and firebase and i'm noting getting enough help from internet or expo docs.Please tell me how to send on click push notification to specific user

Answer (score 2):

Is simple - i create some 'service' for this, follow my code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Permissions, Notifications } from 'expo';

export const registerForPushNotificationsAsync= async() => {
settings = {}
try{
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
        // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app install, so this will only ask on iOS
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        finalStatus = status;
    }
    // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted')
        settings['token'] = ''
    else{
        // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
        let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
        settings['token'] = token
    }
    settings['status'] = finalStatus
}
catch(e){
    settings['token'] = '' 
    settings['status'] = ''
    console.log('error notification ',e)
}
    return settings;
}
```

You save the token and when you want to send push notification you call `sendPushNotification` function with this token:

```
export const sendPushNotification = (token, title, body) => {
    return fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        to: token,
        title: title,
        body: body,
        data: { message: `${title} - ${body}` },
        sound: "default",
        icon: "/assets/images/lionIcon180-180.png",
        android:{
            icon: "/assets/images/lionIcon180-180.png",
            sound:"default"
        }
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'POST',
    });
}
```

Comment: But these method not working for different users it is only registering devices and any user on that device is getting notification i want to send notification to only one user doesn't matter on what device he/she is

Comment: You can send a message to a specific user - `registerForPushNotificationsAsync` you save the token and when you need to send something to this user with this token you call `sendPushNotification`

Comment: I'm not getting your answer can you please explain or help me some code expample?

Comment: step by step, you can get user token with `registerForPushNotificationsAsync` ?

Comment: you can get user token with registerForPushNotificationsAsync ?

Comment: hey @MuhammadHaseeb did you manage to get this working, I am struggling with the same issue. I got the notifications set up with expo, same as you, but not sure how to get a specific user to receive them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expo's `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();` method to get the push token which you can then use to send a notification to that user later by making a post request to this endpoint https://your-server.com/users/push-token.

> https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/

You could make a request like so:

```
fetch(PUSH_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      token: {
        value: "PUSH_TOKEN_OF_USER",
      },
      user: {
        username: 'Jhon',
      },
    }),
  })
```